# Spark SQL into raw SQL statement

Tags: java, sql, scala, apache-spark

Is there a programmatic way to convert/output SPARK SQL code into just raw SQL statements:

```
val DF = goodDF
  .join(anotherDF, Seq("table"))
  .filter($"column1".isNotNull and $"column2".isNotNull)
```

to

```
select * from goodDF inner join anotherDF ......
```

Thanks

Comment: An `inner join` requires an `ON` condition. How can that be derived from your code snippet? e.g. `inner join anotherDF ON goodDF.anotherFK = anotherDF.ID`  The closest I can get to a full select statment is(from that snippet) is:  `select * from goodDF inner join anotherDF where column1 IS NOT NULL and column2 IS NOT NULL` i.e. it is the join condition that is missing